# SQL Server trigger to update another table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables called `Table A` and `Table B`. I have an application which inserts one row into `Table A` and three rows into `Table B` at the same time. As you can see in the screenshot below, we can link these inserted records based on their `ID` column in `Table` A and `TransID` column in `Table B`.

[image]
During the data insert on table B, if any rows out of 3 inserted rows contain a value called `Printed` in the `Printed` column, I want to update my `Table A`'s relevant record's `PrintStatus` column to `Printed` as well.

How do I write a SQL Server trigger for this?

Comment: If your application is doing the inserts, why do you need a trigger for this?  Just let the application do the logic based on the data being inserted.

Comment: You can do this without trigger I think.

Comment: Nobody has access to make changes to the application. It guess its not an open source application.

Comment: Hi Amaud would you be able to explain it to me.

Comment: Im writing the query actually with a trigger. I didn't about the locked code of the application.

Comment: Sure, appreciate if you could post it here as an answer and explain it to me.

Comment: @CrysisHhtht . . . A trigger solution is rather complicated.  It would really need to take updates, inserts, and deletes into account.

Comment: Yes but if Crysis is sure to never update the data, we can do a simple trigger on INSERT.

Comment: @Gordon- I know mate. Unfortunately I couldn't find any other way to do it without writing a trigger for insert.

Answer (score 4):

Well the best solution is to do this in your code(app) but if there is no way,
you can write a Trigger After Insert for Table B like the trigger example below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YourTrigger] ON [dbo].[TableB]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @id INT
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SET @id = (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted WHERE Printed='Printed')   
  UPDATE TableA
  SET PrintStatus='Printed'
  WHERE ID = @id

END
```

May this help you

Comment: yes. I know. will check this trigger out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, will look at them

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 3 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 3 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Good point I didnt see marc. Yes maybe i should add it later. Thanks @marc_s

Answer (score 2):

It could be correct for your problem : (not sure at 100%)

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerTableB
ON TableB
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE TableA AS A
    SET PrintStatus = 'Printed'
    WHERE A.TranID = inserted.ID
        AND 'Printed' = (SELECT MAX(I.Printed)
                         FROM inserted AS I)
```

Comment: Thanks Amaud. Will check this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend querying for the information:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from b
                          where b.id = a.tranid and b.printed = 'Printed'
                         )
             then 'Printed'
        end) as printstatus
from a;
```

This is simpler than writing a query and you can wrap this in a view.

From a performance perspective, an index on `b(id, printed)` should make this pretty fast -- and not slow down inserts.

A trigger can be quite complicated, if you want to take `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s into account.  I prefer to avoid such complication, if possible.

Comment: Gordon after inserting the data they won't be any update or delete operations on inserted data. Hence could you let me know how to update this for a insert trigger